# Output int from array in java increases the integer value

Tags: java

Can someone explain why, when I input values, the output is increased by 9, for all the values stored in the array?

```
    int [] number;
    int numCounter,num;

    userInt validate = new userInt();

    //set the number of array it can hold
    number = new int[100];
    //set the counter to be equal to zero;
    numCounter = 0;
    validate.InputString("enter up to 100 positive integer;");
    while(true){
        validate.InputString("enter 0 to end");
            num = validate.userInt();
                //this will exist the loop statement
                if(num <= 0)
                    break;
            number[numCounter] = num;
            numCounter++;
    }

    //this will print the enter number from the array in reversed order
    for(int i = numCounter - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        System.out.println(number[i] +'\t');
}
```

Comment: What are you seeing and what is it doing?

Comment: You should post `userInt` code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are adding the int value of the tab character to each number, which is 9.

```
System.out.println(number[i] +'\t')
```

If you want to print a TAB after each number, change to :

```
System.out.println(number[i] + "\t");
```

Comment: Bingo! Should be `...+"\t")` instead.

Comment: Got there before me! Excellent catch. +1

Answer (score 3):

```
for(int i = numCounter - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    System.out.println(number[i] +'\t');
```

`number` is of type `int[]`.

Tab in ASCII is 9, as we can see in the ASCII table:

[image]

When the code is being ran, Java sees:

```
int + char
```

It can't add a `char` and an `int` so it needs to promote the `char`. The type with the highest precision in the expression is an `int` type, hence the `char` is turned into its `int` representation. And so, it becomes:

```
int + int
```

To solve this, you need to change your `char` into a `String`. This will give it a higher precision than an `int` and mean that the `int` is promoted to a `String`, which will change the `+` from the *integer addition operator* to the *string concatenation operator*.

**Extra Reading**

- Read about [Arithmetic Promotion](http://www.codemiles.com/java/arithmetic-promotion-t3487.html). This is the process by which all *operands* are promoted to the same precision so they can be manipulated.
- Might as well read about the difference between `'` and `"` in Java. You can see that [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Comment: That's pretty detailed :) +1

Comment: This explains it all :) thanks Chris

Comment: No problem Terry! If you have any more questions then feel free to post a question of similar quality :)

Answer (score 0):

As several others have already mentioned, when your compiler comes across the tab character it evaluates it as an int and does integer addition increasing your array values. Also, just to help you out, instead of having a `true` value as your while-loop condition, consider moving `num<=0` up into the while-loop condition. You can also integrate your array initialization and declaration to reduce the length of your code. Always work to make your code as short as possible. This will help you condense your code which is rather important as you start making larger programs. Also, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) you can find a bit on escape sequences. Remember that single quotes cause your compiler to think "Okay, this is a char," and you don't always want that.